# Computing $ \int_{-\pi}^{0} x \cos(nx) \, {\rm d} x $ via integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Suppose we have to integrate

$$ \int_{-\pi}^{0} x \cos(nx) \, {\rm d} x $$

This is done by integration by parts. The result will be

$$ \frac{1}{n}[x\sin x]_{-\pi}^{0} - \frac{1}{n} \int_{-\pi}^{0} \sin(nx) \, {\rm d} x $$

We divide by $n$ both  parts. Is that correct? But why do we divide both parts?

Comment: When you perform integration by parts, you must differentiate a $u$ inside the integrand, and integrate a $\mathrm dv$ inside the integrand. Here, you differentiate $u=x$ so $\mathrm du=\mathrm dx$ while integrating $\mathrm dv=\cos nx\,\mathrm dx$, which is where your factor of $n$ comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration by parts states that
$$\int uv=u\int v-\int u'\left(\int v\right)$$
Here, we have $$\int_{-\pi}^{0} \underbrace{x}_u \cdot \underbrace{\cos(nx)}_v \, {\rm d} x$$
Thus, we have $$\int_{-\pi}^{0} x \cos(nx) \, {\rm d} x=\left. x\int\cos(nx)\text{ d}x\right|_{x=-\pi}^{x=0}-\int^{0}_{-\pi}1\cdot\left(\int\cos(nx)\text{ d}x\right)\text{ d}x$$
The $\frac1n$ factor in the first term comes from the fact that $$\int\cos(nx)\text{ d}x=\frac 1n\sin(nx)$$ when we make the substitution $$nx\mapsto x,\qquad \text{d}(nx)=n$$
Anyhow, we have $$\left. x\frac 1n\sin(nx)\right|_{x=-\pi}^{x=0}-\int^{0}_{-\pi}\frac 1n\sin(nx)\text{ d}x=\frac{1-n\pi\sin(n\pi)-\cos(n\pi)}{n^2}$$